# image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas, fonts

I am coding a automation interface using tkinter and i have to import a second py file from the first by press of a button, the importing works but i am faced with an error that says "image "pyimage1" doesn't exist", here is the code for the main interface"

```
import tkinter as tk1
window=tk1.Tk()

window.wm_title("Main Interface")

def Function():
    import What

#main
Canvas= tk1.Canvas(window, height=1000, width=1000)
Canvas.grid(row=30, column=20)


Label1=tk1.Label(Canvas, text="WELCOME TO DIGITAL AUTOMATION", bg="#eddea8", font="Verdana 34", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
Label1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label1=tk1.Label(Canvas, text="What do you want to perform ? ", bg="#eddea8", font="Verdana 18", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
Label1.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label2=tk1.Label(Canvas, text="Schedule A message ?", bg="#33CCFF", font="Verdana 12")
Label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

Button1=tk1.Button(Canvas, bg="#59cced", text="Press Here", font="Verdana 18", command=Function)
Button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

----------and here is the code for the whatsapp automation---------------------------------

```
from tkinter import *
import pywhatkit

#import pkg_resources.py2_warn
root = Tk()
root.wm_iconbitmap("icon/default.ico")
root.wm_title("Mscheduler")
bg = PhotoImage(file = "1187248.png")
#root.geometry("965x250")
#Function
def Function():
    n=Entry1.get()
    m=Entry2.get()
    L=Entry3.get()
    I=Entry4.get()
    y="+91"
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(y+n,str(m),int(L),int(I))
    Entry1.delete(0,END)
    Entry2.delete(0,END)
    Entry3.delete(0,END)
    Entry4.delete(0,END)
    

#def delete():
    #Entry1.delete(0,END)

    

#mainscreen
Canvas = Canvas(root, height=1000, width=1000)
Canvas.grid(row=30, column=20)

Canvas.create_image( 0, 0, image = bg, anchor = "nw")

Label1 = Label(Canvas, text="Mscheduler",bg='#99e6ff',font="Verdana 34", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
Label1.grid(row=0,column=1)

Label2= Label(Canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text="Phone no:",font="verdana 18")
Label2.grid(row=2 , column=0)

#Canvas.create_text(105, 115, text="Phone No.:",font="verdana 18")
#Canvas.create_text.grid(row=2 , column=0)

Entry1=Entry(Canvas,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
Entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)

Label3= Label(Canvas,bg="#A9ECFF", text=" Message:",font="verdana 18")
Label3.grid(row=3 , column=0)
#Canvas.create_text(115, 170, text="Message:",font="verdana 18")

Entry2=Entry(Canvas,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
Entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)

Label4= Label(Canvas,bg="#A9ECFF", text="      Hour:",font="verdana 18")
Label4.grid(row=4 , column=0)
#Canvas.create_text(135, 225, text="  Hour:",font="verdana 18")

Entry3=Entry(Canvas,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
Entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)

Label5= Label(Canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text="  Minutes:",font="verdana 18")
Label5.grid(row=5 , column=0)
#Canvas.create_text(135,225 text="Minutes:", font="verdana 18")
#Canvas.create_text(200, 350, text="Phone No.:",font="verdana 18")


Entry4=Entry(Canvas,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
Entry4.grid(row=5, column=1)

Button1=Button(Canvas, bg="#d1d1e0", text="send --->", font="verdana 18", borderwidth=3, command=Function)
Button1.grid(row=7, column=2)

#Button1=Button(Canvas, bg="#d1d1e0", text="delete", font="verdana 18", borderwidth=5, command=delete)
#Button1.grid(row=7, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

i tried using tk.Toplevel and all but it doesnt seem to work, please help

Comment: At the time that I write this, there are 30 questions on this site specifically about that error message. Have you read through their answers?

Answer (score 0):

This task does not require the use of two instances of Tk. You should read about splitting a program into modules and about naming variables in python. The sample program consists of two files main.py and whatsappauto.py. I didn't import some libraries to make it easier to show how to work with two modules.

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

import whatsappauto   # Importing a second file

window=tk.Tk()

window.wm_title("Main Interface")

def Function(window):
# Calling a function from another file
    whatsappauto.top_level(window)

#main
canvas= tk.Canvas(window, height=1000, width=1000)
canvas.grid(row=30, column=20)


Label1=tk.Label(canvas, text="WELCOME TO DIGITAL AUTOMATION", bg="#eddea8", font="Verdana 34", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
Label1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label1=tk.Label(canvas, text="What do you want to perform ? ", bg="#eddea8", font="Verdana 18", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
Label1.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label2=tk.Label(canvas, text="Schedule A message ?", bg="#33CCFF", font="Verdana 12")
Label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

Button1=tk.Button(canvas, bg="#59cced", text="Press Here", font="Verdana 18", command=partial(Function, window))
Button1.grid(row=3, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

```
whatsappauto.py
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


def Function(Entry1, Entry2, Entry3, Entry4):
    n = Entry1.get()
    m = Entry2.get()
    L = Entry3.get()
    I = Entry4.get()
    y = "+91"
#    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(y + n, str(m), int(L), int(I))
    Entry1.delete(0, tk.END)
    Entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
    Entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
    Entry4.delete(0, tk.END)


def top_level(root):

    global canvas_bg

    newWindow1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newWindow1.wm_iconbitmap("icon/default.ico")
    newWindow1.wm_title("Mscheduler")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(newWindow1)
    canvas.pack()

    canvas_bg = tk.PhotoImage(file='1187248.png')
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas_bg, anchor="nw")


    Label1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Mscheduler", bg='#99e6ff', font="Verdana 34", relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
    Label1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label2 = tk.Label(canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text="Phone no:", font="verdana 18")
    Label2.grid(row=2, column=0)


    Entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
    Entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)

    Label3 = tk.Label(canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text=" Message:", font="verdana 18")
    Label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    # Canvas.create_text(115, 170, text="Message:",font="verdana 18")

    Entry2 = tk.Entry(canvas, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
    Entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)

    Label4 = tk.Label(canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text="      Hour:", font="verdana 18")
    Label4.grid(row=4, column=0)


    Entry3 = tk.Entry(canvas, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
    Entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)

    Label5 = tk.Label(canvas, bg="#A9ECFF", text="  Minutes:", font="verdana 18")
    Label5.grid(row=5, column=0)


    Entry4 = tk.Entry(canvas, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 18", relief="ridge", borderwidth=3)
    Entry4.grid(row=5, column=1)

    Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, bg="#d1d1e0", text="send --->", font="verdana 18",
                        borderwidth=3, command=partial(Function, Entry1, Entry2, Entry3, Entry4))
    Button1.grid(row=7, column=2)
```